# Install error when trying to update android application programmatically

Tags: android, apk, packageinstaller

I wanted to update my `Android` application to newer version by downloading it from a server but it didn't work(both in code and manually). here is my code:

```
MimeTypeMap map = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
String ext = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(file.getName());
String type = map.getMimeTypeFromExtension(ext);
if (type == null)
    type = "application/vnd.android.package-archive";

if(outputFile.exists()) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    Uri data = Uri.fromFile(outputFile);
    intent.setDataAndType(data, type);
    MyContext.startActivity(intent);  // this line cause parse error

} else {
    // display error message -- not happened in my case
    Toast.makeText(MyContext, "File was not downloaded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

I test my downloaded apk(new version) file manually with `Google Chrome` and the file downloaded successfully, but it couldn't be installed(Error: app not installed).

**Automatically install error**
[image: Automatically install error]

Do anybody knows what's wrong? Do i miss something necessary to install new version of application without uninstalling old one(uninstalling old version would wipe out whole data)? please help me.

**EDIT: It turns out that file that i tried to install, didn't downloaded completely.**

Comment: Usually this indicates that you tried updating an app signed with a different certificate (keystore). Probably one is your release build, the other debug, or you used 2 different computers, etc...

Comment: The file was corrupted. Please create a new apk and then try to install.

Comment: @DavidMedenjak: yeah, i thought about signature problem too and generate signed apk again, it doesn't work

Comment: @Rajasekhar: the file installed correctly after uninstalling old version.

Comment: ok that's cool.

Comment: yeah but he didn't accept any of them